# Flask-SQLAlchemy changes don't persist

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a web application, where user action can affect some bar graphs (seen in the gif below). Sometimes, changes aren't saved. When I reload the page, the changed bar graphs are shown (indicating that the user's action's were saved). When I reload the page again, sometimes the updated bar graphs and corresponding list are shown. Other times, they are not.

[image: The bug in action]

Here's the code for the view:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    '''homepage for application'''

    # redirect users who go to home page but aren't logged in
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for("landing"))

    # reset the session
    db.session.flush()

    # get most recent entered weight
    try:
        last_weight = WeightEntry.query.filter_by(user_id = current_user.user_id).order_by(WeightEntry.date)[-1]
    except IndexError:
        return error("No weight recorded. Please contact support.")

    return render_template("home.html",
                            today= Today(current_user.user_id),
                            foods = [food for food in FoodEntry.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.user_id).all() if food.is_today() == True],
                            options =  sorted(Food.query.filter(Food.user_id==current_user.user_id).all(), key=lambda x: x.name),
                            last_weight = last_weight)
```

I added the `db.session.flush()` in an attempt to solve the problem, but that didn't work.

The changes (logged foods) are stored here:

```
@app.route("/log_food", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def log_food():
    # add foods given by the user
    if request.method == "POST":
        for food in request.form.getlist("logged_food"):
            try:
                added_food = Food.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.user_id, name=food).first()
                x = FoodEntry(
                    food_id = added_food.food_id,
                    user_id = current_user.user_id)
                db.session.add(x)
                db.session.commit()
            except:
                return error("Unable to log food.")

        return redirect(url_for("home"))
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!

Comment: add the code where you save the changes please, and the engine configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `db.session.commit()` to the page functions.

For example, for the homepage: I did:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    '''homepage for application'''

    db.session.commit()
    ...
```

Comment: you already have that line of code in the question, what's the difference ?